# Does Windows support tcp TIME_WAIT reuse?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

My PC is Windows 7 and I'm wondering if there is a similar option to turn on TIME_WAIT reuse, like `tcp_tw_reuse` on Linux?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the delay in the reuse of TCP sockets is not optional, regardless of OS. It is a mandatory part of the protocol specification.

You can configure it in the registry.

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`

`TcpTimedWaitDelay     REG_DWORD    0x1e (30)`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938217.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The question I'm wondering is in the case of TIME_WAIT on the server end, if a client (e.g., a NAT) tries to connect to the same socket, what would happen?  And does `tcp_tw_reuse` make a difference?

Comment: This is exactly this question http://serverfault.com/q/759453/267216

Comment: @stackoverflower http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html